# Retrieving original type for a generic delegate after it is boxed in a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, delegates, boxing

**Context - Part1**

I have a delegate to build complex numbers from real and imaginary parts which is defined like this:

```
public delegate T BuildFromRealImagPartsDelegate<out T, in TUnderlying>(TUnderlying real, TUnderlying imag);
```

This delegate uses generics because, in my situation, both complex type and underlying type for real and imaginary parts can change... Well, this is not very important regarding the issue I want to solve but for instance, for `System.Numerics.Complex` which is based on `System.Double`, this gives:

```
BuildFromRealImagPartsDelegate<Complex, double> buildFromRealImag = (r, i) => new Complex(r, i);
```

**Context - Part2**

Now for handling the various situations I may encounter, this delegate is inserted in a dictionary with the many other ones:

```
var dictionnary = new Dictionary<Type, BuildFromRealImagPartsDelegate<Object, Object>>();
dictionnary.Add(typeof(Complex), (r, i) => buildFromRealImag);
```

NB: Here what is important is that the dictionnary uses `Object` as generic type. Indeed I need to collect many different delegates with many different types so this was my best option.

**The problem**

When extracting a delegate from the dictionary I would like to find back the originak underlying type for real and imaginary parts. But because dictionary uses `Object` I'm locked and cannot find the type that was used to define the delegate:

```
var deleg = dictionnary[typeof(Complex)];
var underlyingTypeForRealImag = deleg.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[1]; // Here returns typeof(object) but would like to obtain original type (i.e. typeof(double))
```

Is there a quick solution or should I manage to pass initial type for real/imag parts when adding delegates in the dictionary ?

**Edit**

Here is sample code ready to compile as console application:

```
namespace BoxedDelegate
{
    using System;
    using System.Numerics;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public delegate T BuildFromRealImagPartsDelegate<out T, in TUnderlying>(TUnderlying real, TUnderlying imag);

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Delegate for System.Numerics.Complex
            BuildFromRealImagPartsDelegate<Complex, double> buildFromRealImag = (r, i) => new Complex(r, i);

            // Boxing the delegate into the dictionary
            var dictionnary = new Dictionary<Type, BuildFromRealImagPartsDelegate<Object, Object>>();
            dictionnary.Add(typeof(Complex), (r, i) => buildFromRealImag);

            // Retrieving the delegate and trying to
            // figure out what was the original type for real/imag parts
            var deleg = dictionnary[typeof(Complex)];
            var underlyingTypeForRealImag = deleg.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[1]; // Here returns typeof(object) but would like to obtain original type (i.e. typeof(double))

            Console.WriteLine("Type for real/imag part is: {0}", underlyingTypeForRealImag);
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is to retrieve generic type that was used for real imag/part at the time the dedelegate was ccreated (i.e. before it was inserted into the dictionary) ... If possible of course !!  ... If not I have a workaround (with additional dictionary containing the type used for real/imag part) but truly I would like to known if there's direct solution.

Comment: What makes you think your dictionary contains anything other than instances of `BuildFromRealImagPartsDelegate<Object, Object>`? The code you posted (particularly the call to `Add()`) doesn't even look like it would compile. Are you saying you are wrapping one delegate by invoking with parameters passed to another, outer delegate?

Comment: @PeterDuniho I can ensure this is compiling, see this [sample console code](https://gist.github.com/CitizenInsane/77ef6ca64f29609c6f28) ... I don't say that dictionary contains something else than object ... but was willing for retrieving original generic types used to create the delegate before to insert it in the dictionary (if possible of course!!).

Comment: You're right...I see it can compile. But it doesn't seem like it would do what you want. Your `Add()` call stores a delegate to an anonymous method that, given two `Complex` values, returns a _delegate_ reference value, i.e. an instance of `BuildFromRealImagPartsDelegate<Complex, double>`. Is that really what you wanted? I mean, it does make getting the type of the delegate easier (very easy), but why bother creating a delegate that way? Why not just store values of type `object`?

Comment: And please do not use external web sites to present any part of your question. A StackOverflow question should be entirely self-contained. If the code's so big you think it belongs on another site, then it's too big to expect anyone looking at your question to even bother with. Even worse though, links to external sites regularly become stale, rendering the StackOverflow question useless to future readers. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for advice on how to construct a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example that helps illustrate your question.

Comment: Could you just store the target type separately? That way you wouldn't have to look at the delegate. Also can you provide any detail on how you will be using this? It looks like you are going to hit a place where you can't write anything since your compiler doesn't know the two types involved and thus you can't get the correct delegate type to call it successfully.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks. I'm doing things that complex because I want to do automatic marshalling of numeric types in C# with other types in a native API (CreateFrom<T>(), GetContentAs<T>() + Dictionary to register well-know types or custom ones). At some point was needing to find back type used for real/imag part and was looking for quick solution before to use auxillary dictionnary to store it.

Comment: @Guvante Thanks, that's the workaround I finally used ! :)